# How to handle DatePicker (Calendar Control) using selenium + Java?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have a scenario to enter Date Of Birth for some agents. I gave Agent Names, DOB in excel. 
I wrote the code in Java. But while running the script it is not working.

How can I automate Date Picker for the required date using Selenium?

Comment: Please provide the html for the calendar/date picker.

Comment: I am trying to paste the image. But Stack Overflow site says that i should have 10 reputations :(